# Dealing With Sequential Result Sets In XML Report Builder

Tags: xml, xslt, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I'm currently having difficulty reading in some XML data source.

Usually, I have dealt with this kind of result:

```
<resultset>
    <result>
        <name>...</name>
    </result>
    <result>
        <name>...</name>
    </result>
    <result>
        <name>...</name>
    </result>
</resultset>
```

Where each result returned in the result set is the same name and can be collected easily.

However, in a new result return, they are coming in the form of:

```
<resultset>
    <_1>
        <name>...</name>
    </_1>
    <_2>
        <name>...</name>
    </_2>
    <_3>
        <name>...</name>
    </_3>
</resultset>
```

Here each result returned is a sequential ID, following an underscore.

I'm not sure how best to use these results, I am trying with the query:

```
<Query>
   <ElementPath>
            <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">
                        apiresult{}/resultset{}/_1
            </ElementPath> 
   </ElementPath>
 </Query>
```

Unfortunately, this will only bring back the first result - is there some sort of wildcard I can use in place of '_1' to bring back _2, _3 and so on?

I have tried to use a wildcard such as,

```
apiresult{}/resultset{}/_*
```

Or

```
apiresult{}/resultset{}/_%
```

But, no luck...

Using a single asterisk, it does not work, I get the error:

```
apiresult{}/resultset{}/*


The Value expression for the text box ‘id’ refers to the field ‘id’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.
----------------------------
The definition of the report '' is invalid.
----------------------------
An error occurred during local report processing.
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="resultset//name">
    <each><xsl:value-of select="name(..)" />: <xsl:value-of select="."/></each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs:

```
    <each>_1: ...</each>
    <each>_2: ...</each>
    <each>_3: ...</each>
```

Comment: That would be fantastic!, But, is there a way to integrate this inside the <query> </query> structure that report builder uses?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Report Builder. This is just the xslt-answer.